# How to import only one field from a JSON file to MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, import

How to import only one field from a JSON file to MongoDB?

JSON Example:

```
  "ix": "79150fa9b2f74f20811fbb04ae446c38",
  "dataTmp": [
    {
      "ix": "b45d17133c304219965d9191bc8ca6b5",
      "temp": "abcTmp1"
    },
    {
      "ix": "b45d17133c304219965d9191bc8ca6b6",
      "temp": "123Tmp2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to import only array "dataTmp". I've tried it (unsuccessfully for only field):

**mongoimport --file "test_mongoDB.json" --type json --db local --collection collection_111 --drop**

In documentation shows up option **--fields**, but can't be used for JSON file.

Is It possible?

Answer (score 0):

From [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/):

> If you attempt to include --fields when importing JSON data, mongoimport will return an error. --fields is only for CSV or TSV imports.

So you need to extract the `dataTmp` field using a [`jq` CLI tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) before doing import.

```bash
jq '.dataTmp' test_mongoDB.json > dataTmp.json
mongoimport --file "dataTmp.json" --type json --db local --collection collection_111 --drop --jsonArray
```

Note that I've added `--jsonArray` argument to `mongoimport`, since you now import an array.

Comment: Ok, but editing the files or extract field to copy in another file, is not an option. That's why I asked if there is a way to read a specific field from JSON. If MongoDB allows doing this field extraction during the import, that's what I need.

Comment: @wBB You don't have to create a temp file, you could pipe the output of `jq` directly into `mongoimport`.  When I need to preprocess very large JSON files with `jq`, that's what I do.